# bootstrap 4 carousel : last item to first item not smooth

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend, slider

I have my bootstrap 4 carousel on my homepage. Everything work except when im on the last slide of the carousel, when it return to the first slide, the animation dont work and the render is ugly because of that.

That is my code :

```
<section class="div_homepage">

<div id="carousel_homepage" class="carousel slide carousel-animation" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-indicators">

        <div data-target="#carousel_homepage" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
            <a href="{{ path('vdf_to_offer')}}" alt="carousel pictures">
                {{ 'sylius.shop.to_offer'| trans }}
            </a>
        </div>

        <div data-target="#carousel_homepage" data-slide-to="1" >
            <a href="{{ path('vdf_for_me')}}" alt="carousel pictures">
                {{ 'sylius.shop.for_me'| trans }}
            </a>
        </div>

        <div data-target="#carousel_homepage" data-slide-to="2">
            <a href="{{ path('vdf_for_professionals')}}" alt="carousel pictures">
                {{ 'sylius.shop.for_professionals'| trans }}
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item-height carousel-item active">
            <picture class="bg_home">
                <source media="(max-width: 767px)" srcset="{{ asset('/vdf/shop/bg_to_offer_mobile.jpg') | imagine_filter('background_home')}}"  type="image/webp">
                <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px)" srcset="{{ asset('/vdf/shop/bg_to_offer_tablet.jpg') | imagine_filter('background_home')}}" type="image/webp">
                <img id="test" class="bg_home d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="{{ asset('/vdf/shop/bg_to_offer.jpg') | imagine_filter('background_home')}}" alt="background picture"  type="image/webp">
            </picture>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                <a class="link-page" href="{{ path('vdf_to_offer')}}" >Pour Offrir</a>
                <h5>A la recherche d’un cadeau chic et élégant ? Les verres et coffrets personnalisés n’attendent plus que vous.</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="call_to_action_carousel">
                <a href="{{ path('vdf_to_offer')}}" class="btn_vdf_white" >
                    {{ 'sylius.shop.homepage.go_to_offer'| trans }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item-height carousel-item">
            <picture class="bg_home">
                <source media="(max-width: 767px)" srcset="{{ asset('/vdf/shop/bg_for_me_mobile.jpg') | imagine_filter('background_home')}}"  type="image/webp">
                <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px)" srcset="{{ asset('/vdf/shop/bg_for_me_tablet.jpg') | imagine_filter('background_home')}}"  type="image/webp">
                <img id="test" class="bg_home d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="{{ asset('/vdf/shop/bg_for_me.jpg') | imagine_filter('background_home')}}" alt="background picture"  type="image/webp">
            </picture>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                <a class="link-page " href="{{ path('vdf_for_me')}}">Pour Moi</a>
                <h5>Des verres personnalisés uniques et créatifs pour une utilisation personnelle !</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="call_to_action_carousel">
                <a href="{{ path('vdf_for_me')}}" class="btn_vdf_white">
                    {{ 'sylius.shop.homepage.go_to_for_me'| trans }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item-height carousel-item">
            <picture class="bg_home">
                <source media="(max-width: 767px)" srcset="{{ asset('/vdf/shop/bg_for_pro_mobile.jpg') | imagine_filter('background_home')}}"  type="image/webp">
                <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px)" srcset="{{ asset('/vdf/shop/bg_for_pro_tablet.jpg') | imagine_filter('background_home')}}"  type="image/webp">
                <img id="test" class="bg_home d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="{{ asset('/vdf/shop/bg_for_pro.jpg') | imagine_filter('background_home') }}" type="image/webp" alt="background picture">
            </picture>
             <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block">
                 <a class="link-page" href="{{ path('vdf_for_professionals')}}">Pour les Pros</a>
                <h5>Découvrez une vaisselle moderne et tendance pour vos établissements ou évènements festifs.</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="call_to_action_carousel">
                <a href="{{ path('vdf_for_professionals')}}" class="btn_vdf_white">
                    {{ 'sylius.shop.homepage.go_to_for_pro'| trans }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel_homepage" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="chevron left icon thin" style="font-size: 3em"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel_homepage" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="chevron right icon thin" style="font-size: 3em"></i>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

does someone have any solution to fix it please ? I dont understand what is the problem. I use bootstrap 4 and animate with theses links :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
...
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: sorry i didnt say hi

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't worry, you can always edit your question.